# How to solve ntdll, msado15 and stackhash errors while running a windows app?

Tags: windows, windows-7, vb6, crash, ntdll

I have an app which is running perfectly in my system and also on a few other customers as well. But I have a particular customer for which this is not working. I have tried the following:

1. Updating Windows.
2. turning off firewall.
3. turning off DEP.
4. turning off UAC.

But none of this works. Following are the errors that come.

**First:**

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name:          APPCRASH
Application Name:            myApp.exe
Application Version:         3.1.0.98
Application Timestamp:       52931ef4
Fault Module Name:           ntdll.dll
Fault Module Version:        6.1.7601.18205
Fault Module Timestamp:      51db96c5
Exception Code:              c0000005
Exception Offset:            00056018
OS Version:                  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:                   1033
Additional Information 1:    d492
Additional Information 2:    d4929f89b5901f5adaff2902c08af6fa
Additional Information 3:    fd01
Additional Information 4:    fd01b5c431f746d7526bc265e84208c2
```

**Second:**

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name:          APPCRASH
Application Name:            myApp.exe
Application Version:         3.1.0.98
Application Timestamp:       51d51f8b
Fault Module Name:           msado15.dll
Fault Module Version:        6.1.7601.17857
Fault Module Timestamp:      4fcee2cc
Exception Code:              c0000005
Exception Offset:            000302d8
OS Version:                  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:                   1033
Additional Information 1:    3047
Additional Information 2:    304731efac0f2df745479a919b6ba54b
Additional Information 3:    c5d9
Additional Information 4:    c5d92a2744df3b35f2cd5ee4004f8239
```

**Third:**

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name:          APPCRASH
Application Name:            myApp.exe
Application Version:         3.1.0.98
Application Timestamp:       51d51f8b
Fault Module Name:           StackHash_753d
Fault Module Version:        6.1.7600.16385
Fault Module Timestamp:      4a5bd98a
Exception Code:              c0000374
Exception Offset:            00008518
OS Version:                  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:                   1033
Additional Information 1:    753d
Additional Information 2:    753d342126021b53e7ba0868794c2464
Additional Information 3:    a931
Additional Information 4:    a931d4a14b5a731fcf5350897f9ad699
```

Comment: Whats the actual error/exception message?

Comment: These errors got solved by downgrading to Oracle 10g client.